# How to stop the counter from increasing when refreshing the page

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$score=0;
$sql10=mysql_query("select * from image WHERE fromUser='".$_SESSION['email']."' order by id desc");
$score1=mysql_fetch_array($sql10);
$answer=$score1['Correct_answer'];
echo $answer;

$sql13=mysql_query("select * from image WHERE toUser='".$_SESSION['email']."' order by id desc");
$score2=mysql_fetch_array($sql13);
$answer2=$score2['User_answer2'];
echo $answer2;


strcasecmp($answer,$answer2);
if(strcasemp)

echo $score +=1;
```

As u can see I am comparing the answers and if both are equal I want the score to increase by one. But the code is not working any hint???

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

Comment: *slap*. turn on displaying warnings.

Comment: Shouldn't this be:
if(strcasemp==0)
{
echo $score +=1;

}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not using the comparison to increment the score.  The `if (strcasecmp)` line doesn't do anything.  You're doing the `strcasecmp($answer,$answer2)` above, but not storing or using the result of the comparison.  Also, `strcasecmp()` returns 0 for equality.  Instead, try:

```
if(strcasecmp($answer,$answer2) === 0) {
  echo $score +=1;

}
```

To prevent this from incrementing every time you refresh the page, you'll need to store some indication in `$_SESSION` that you have already processed it.

```
session_start();

// Check if it hasn't already been answered.
if (!isset($_SESSION['answered']))
{
    // Do all your queries to check the answers.
    // etc...
    // etc...

    if(strcasecmp($answer,$answer2) === 0) {
      echo $score +=1;

      // Store an indicator in $_SESSION so this doesn't get processed again
      $_SESSION['answered'] = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: same typo as in OP's question

Comment: the `if (strcasecmp)` line does one thing: it emits a warning :)

Comment: I tried your code it doesn't work even if $answer and $answer2 is equal  :-(

Comment: No the score is not stored just I want it to be displayed on the screen. The answers are stored in a database as varchar >>> how can i know if it is unicode or not??

Comment: I think the (===) should be (==) right??? but even when i tried both they did not work.

Comment: `===` is correct to match int 0. Please post example answers as are passed to strcasecmp()

Comment: ok user1 posts the correct answer like "real" from a radio button option then that ansewr is stored in the database under the column (correct_answer) then when user2 chooses the same answer ("real") it is stored in (user_answer). so I used strcasecmp for the comparison

Comment: Yesssssssss Michael thaaaanx, my program now works fine but i am usually facing the problem of refreshing the page. Every time I clicked on refresh the counter increases by one do u know how to avoid it????

Comment: @Amal see addition above. Use `$_SESSION` to indicate if it's already been processed, then on refresh the code won't run if it previously has